# Why does my Python code only add up the price of the last item in my shopping cart?

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a python code that lets you add items to your shopping cart then once you type "done" it is supposed to add up the prices of each item you added to your shopping cart and then tell you the total price.

My issue is that once I type "done" it only adds up the price of the last item that I added to my shopping cart then prints it out.

```
shopping_cart = [""]

food = shopping_cart

#Stock
stock = {
    "\nFruit\n\n"
    "banana": 50,
    "apple": 15,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15,

    "\nDrinks\n\n"
    "apple juice": 10,
    "orange juice": 10,
    "pinapple juice": 10,
    "milk": 15,

    "\nSnacks\n\n"
    "chips": 20,
    "cookies": 20,
    "chocolate": 25,
    "lollies": 50
}

#Prices 
prices = {
    #Fruit
    "banana": 10,
    "apple": 5,
    "orange": 5,
    "pear": 5,

    #Drinks
    "apple juice": 5,
    "orange juice": 5,
    "pinapple juice": 5,
    "milk": 4.80,

    #Snacks
    "chips": 7,
    "cookies": 4,
    "chocolate": 6,
    "lollies": 5.50
    
}

#Loop
while True:
    item = input("\nEnter an item: ").lower()
    shopping_cart.append(item)

    if item == 'done':
        break

    if item == 'cart':
        print(shopping_cart)

    if item == 'stock':
        for k, v in stock.items():
            print(k + ":", v)


#Define the bill variable
def shopping_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for key in prices:
        for key in stock:
            for item in food:
                if item == key in prices:
                    total += prices[key]
        break 
    print("Your bill total equals $", total)
    print("Thank you for shopping at B&K Supermarket!")

shopping_bill(food)
```

Comment: Reduce your code to find out. But also, why are you using a dict that mixes "labels" with "data"`? If you have multiple types of stock, properly nest that dictionary. Your stock dict should be three entries. Fruit, drinks, and snacks, and each of those should be their own dict. Same for your prices. But what you should _really_ be doing is modeling this properly, with a class that models things that have names, prices, and categories, instead of just plain dicts.

Comment: `if item == key in prices` What do you expect this line of code to do?

Comment: The bill function has `for key in prices` and then the next line is `for key in stock`, so you just overwrote the `key` variable from the outer loop...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am pretty knew and am not sure what labels are. I am using a dictionary because I have never used it before and wanted to try it out and when I first started this code I looked up some code and most of them used dictionary so I thought I was supposed to.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried removing that and it now just sums up the value of the first item I added into the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the same as the other answer but checks that the stock doesn't go below 0.

```
shopping_cart = []

food = shopping_cart

#Stock
stock = {
    #Fruit
    "banana": 50,
    "apple": 15,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15,

    #Drinks
    "apple juice": 10,
    "orange juice": 10,
    "pinapple juice": 10,
    "milk": 15,

    #Snacks
    "chips": 20,
    "cookies": 20,
    "chocolate": 25,
    "lollies": 50
}

#Prices 
prices = {
    #Fruit
    "banana": 10,
    "apple": 5,
    "orange": 5,
    "pear": 5,

    #Drinks
    "apple juice": 5,
    "orange juice": 5,
    "pinapple juice": 5,
    "milk": 4.80,

    #Snacks
    "chips": 7,
    "cookies": 4,
    "chocolate": 6,
    "lollies": 5.50
    
}

#Define the bill variable
def shopping_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for key in stock:
       total += food.count(key) * prices[key]
    print("Your bill total equals $", total)
    print("Thank you for shopping at B&K Supermarket!")

#Loop
while True:
    item = input("\nEnter an item: ").lower()


    if item == 'done':
        shopping_bill(shopping_cart)
        break

    if item == 'cart':
        print(shopping_cart)
        next

    if item == 'stock':
        for k, v in stock.items():
            print(k + ":", v)
        next

    for key in stock:
       if item == key:
              if stock[item] > 0:
                     shopping_cart.append(item)  
                     stock[item] -= 1
                     print("added to cart")
              else:
                     print("out of stock")
```

Comment: What does the "next" line do?

Comment: @SwiftAU It goes to the next iteration of the loop without running the remaining code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but does it need to be in this code?

Comment: @SwiftAU I don't think it does

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems here. The first is that you're defining food as shopping_cart before the user has entered their shopping list. Thus, it remains an empty list.

To fix this, move `food = shopping_cart` to after the `while True` loop, like so:

```
while True:
    item = input("\nEnter an item: ").lower()
    shopping_cart.append(item)

    if item == 'done':
        break

    if item == 'cart':
        print(shopping_cart)

    if item == 'stock':
        for k, v in stock.items():
            print(k + ":", v)

food = shopping_cart
```

The second problem is that you're adding "\nFruit\n\n" and similar things to the dictionary up the top. You need to comment these out so the code doesn't think they're parts of the dictionary.

```
stock = {
    #fruit
    "banana": 50,
    "apple": 15,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15,

    #drinks
    "apple juice": 10,
    "orange juice": 10,
    "pinapple juice": 10,
    "milk": 15,

    
    "chips": 20,
    "cookies": 20,
    "chocolate": 25,
    "lollies": 50
}
```

Entering this into the prompt with the code changes above

```
> banana
> apple
> done
```

produces

```
Your bill total equals $ 15
Thank you for shopping at B&K Supermarket!
```